# Implementing a lambda layer within a Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement an external lambda function from a Keras model. But the function is called twice or the '### x' and '### x_reshape'are printed twice. How to eliminate this?

```
def RA_reshape(x):
    print('\n### x ', x)
    x_reshape = K.reshape(x, [1, x.shape[1].value, x.shape[2].value, x.shape[3].value])
    print('\n### x_reshape ', x_reshape)
    return x_reshape

def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = None):
    inputs = Input(input_size)

    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)

    RA_0 = Lambda(lambda y: RA_reshape(x=y) )
    conv1 = RA_0(conv1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to call it like that :

```
def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = None):
    inputs = Input(input_size)

    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)

    RA_0 = Lambda(RA_reshape)(conv1)
```

Tell me if that working !

Answer (score 0):

This is Keras working internally and building "the graph", it does call functions twice and there is nothing much we can do.

Notice that since it's a graph, it will not print the values as you want! It will print only the symbolic tensors.

For printing the data you need to create a little model only to predict the data you want to see. Or you need to enable eager mode and not use "predict", but manually go calling each layer with a tensor.